# Recycler view items overlap each other when the adapter is refreshed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've a nested recyclerview with parent recyclerview have different type of inner horizontal scrolling recyclerviews. As in the added picture

[image]

The issue is with the Trending now inner recyclerview, the item of this recyclerview has all these cards long short and very-short and I'm changing the visibility in onBindView according to the response which tells me which card to show,

This works perfectly fine but whenever I refresh my main adapter the trending now section becomes distorted like this

[image]

If I refresh adapter again it gets back to it's original shape, I'm not able to find what is the issue here.

Code blow :

So my json response is like this, I've list of widgets and we have differents type of widgets to show different types of inner recyclerview, even the height width of those widgets is from the api response,

```
"results": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "widget_type_id": 1,
    "widget_type": "FixSizeCard",
    "widget_left_margin": 20,
    "widget_right_margin": 20,
    "card_items": [
      {
        "web_url": "",
        "screen_id": 39,
        "web_title": "",
        "card_image": "url here",
        "is_clickable": true,
        "card_sequence": 110
      },
      { },
      { }
    ]
    },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "widget_type_id": 3,
    "widget_type": "MIX CARD",
    "widget_left_margin": 20,
    "widget_right_margin": 20,
    "widget_sequence": 300,
    "heading": "Trending now",
    "mix_card_items": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "web_url": "",
            "location": "top",
            "position": "left",
            "card_type": "long",
            "screen_id": 10,
            "web_title": "Discover",
            "card_h_max": 832,
            "card_image": "url here",
            "card_w_max": 616,
            "is_clickable": true,
            "screen_w_percent": 0.4278,
            "width": 462,
            "height": 624
          }
        ],
        "card_sequence": 1
      },
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "web_url": "",
            "location": "top",
            "position": "left",
            "card_type": "short",
            "screen_id": 6,
            "web_title": "Traffic cop",
            "card_h_max": 380,
            "card_image": "",
            "card_w_max": 616,
            "is_clickable": true,
            "screen_w_percent": 0.4278,
            "width": 462,
            "height": 285
          },
          {
            "icon": "",
            "title": "Petrol",
            "web_url": "",
            "location": "bottom",
            "position": "left",
            "subtitle": "(Udham Singh Nagar)",
            "card_type": "fix",
            "screen_id": 19,
            "top_title": "₹97.76",
            "web_title": "",
            "card_h_max": 380,
            "card_w_max": 616,
            "is_clickable": true,
            "top_subtitle": "0.02",
            "screen_w_percent": 0.4278,
            "card_top_bg_color": "#36BA3C",
            "width": 462,
            "height": 285
          },
          {
            "icon": "",
            "title": "Diesel",
            "web_url": "",
            "location": "bottom",
            "position": "right",
            "subtitle": "(Udham Singh Nagar)",
            "card_type": "fix",
            "screen_id": 19,
            "top_title": "₹90.29",
            "web_title": "",
            "card_h_max": 380,
            "card_w_max": 616,
            "is_clickable": true,
            "top_subtitle": "0.02",
            "screen_w_percent": 0.4278,
            "card_top_bg_color": "#36BA3C",
            "width": 462,
            "height": 285
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Other widgets are simple only the the mix card (Trending now ) widget is little tricky

In Trending now I get type of cards, like long, short, very-short, and on the basis of that I need to show the content/cards

Main Outer Adapter, I'm adding only the relevant code cz it's a lot :

```
 homePageAdapter = object : GenericAdapter<HomePageResponseItem, RvHomePageParentItemBinding>(requireContext()) {
            override fun getLayoutResId(viewType: Int?): Int = R.layout.rv_home_page_parent_item

            override fun onBindData(
                model: HomePageResponseItem,
                position: Int,
                dataBinding: RvHomePageParentItemBinding
            ) {

                dataBinding.widgetHomePage.initHomeWidget(model, this@HomePageFragment)
            }
```

**initHomePageMehotd**

```
 fun initHomeWidget(model: HomePageResponseItem, listener: OnHomePageItemClickListener) {
   

    when (model.widgetTypeId) {

        FIXCARDS -> {
            setUpAdapter(model.cardItems, R.layout.rv_homepage_image_only_item)
        }
       
        MIXCARD -> {
            setUpAdapter(model.mixCardItems, R.layout.rv_item_home_page_trending_now)
        }
```

setUpAdapter() function :

```
private fun setUpAdapter(cardItems: List<Any>?, rvHomepageImageOnlyItem: Int) {
    val adapter = object : GenericAdapter<Any, Any>(context) {
        override fun getLayoutResId(viewType: Int?): Int = rvHomepageImageOnlyItem

        override fun onBindData(model: Any, position: Int, dataBinding: Any) {
            when (homePageResponseItem?.widgetTypeId) {
                3 -> {
                    //mix
                    val binding = (dataBinding as RvItemHomePageTrendingNowBinding)
                    val data = (model as MixCardItem)
                    handleInnerCardsVisibility(binding, data)
                }
```

**handleInnerCardsVisibility() function that handles mix card widget visibility  in certain places I'm checking postion as short card can either be on top or at bottm **

```
private fun handleInnerCardsVisibility(
    binding: RvItemHomePageTrendingNowBinding,
    data: MixCardItem
) {

    binding.apply {
        setCardsDimensions(this)
        //only long card
        if (data.items?.get(0)?.cardType.equals("long")) {
            imgTypeLong.apply {
                makeVisible()
                setImageFromUrl(data.items?.get(0)?.cardImageUrl)
                layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    data.items!![0].innerCardWidth!!,
                    data.items!![0].innerCardHeight!!
                )
               
            imgTypeShortTop.makeGone()
            imgTypeShortBottom.makeGone()
            layoutFixVeryShortTop.makeGone()
            layoutFixVeryShortBottom.makeGone()


        } else {
            //short very short and fix cards with position
            imgTypeLong.makeGone()

            data.items?.let { smallCards ->

                for (innerCardData in smallCards) {

                    when (innerCardData.cardType?.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)) {
                        "short" -> {
                            if (innerCardData.location.equals("top")) {
                                Timber.d("HomePageWidget Short Card Top")
                                imgTypeShortTop.apply {
                                    makeVisible()
                                    val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                                    params.apply {
                                        width = innerCardData.innerCardWidth!!
                                        height = innerCardData.innerCardHeight!!
                                    }
                                    layoutParams = params
                                    setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.cardImageUrl)
                                    
                                }
                            } else {
                                Timber.d("HomePageWidget Short Card Bottom")
                                imgTypeShortBottom.apply {
                                    makeVisible()
                                    val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                                    params.apply {
                                        width = innerCardData.innerCardWidth!!
                                        height = innerCardData.innerCardHeight!!
                                    }
                                    layoutParams = params
                                    setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.cardImageUrl)
                                    
                            }
                        }

                        "fix" -> {
                            if (innerCardData.location.equals("top")) {
                                Timber.d("HomePageWidget fix Card top")
                                imgTypeShortTop.makeGone()
                                layoutFixVeryShortTop.apply {
                                    makeVisible()
                                    val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                                    params.apply {
                                        width = innerCardData.innerCardWidth!!
                                        height = innerCardData.innerCardHeight!!
                                    }
                                    layoutParams = params
                                    if (innerCardData.position.equals("left")) {
                                        this.imgLeftImageOnly.makeGone()
                                        val bg = this.containerLeftBg.background
                                        val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(bg)
                                        DrawableCompat.setTint(
                                            drawable,
                                            Color.parseColor(innerCardData.cardTopBgColor)
                                        )
                                        this.containerLeftBg.background = drawable

                                        tv_item_title_left.text = innerCardData.title
                                        tv_price_left.text = innerCardData.topTitle
                                        tv_location_left.text = innerCardData.subtitle
                                        tv_price_change_left.text = innerCardData.topSubtitle
                                        tv_arrow_left.setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.icon)
                                    } else {
                                        this.imgRightImageOnly.makeGone()
                                        tv_item_title_right.text = innerCardData.title
                                        tv_price_right.text = innerCardData.topTitle
                                        tv_location_right.text = innerCardData.subtitle
                                        tv_price_change_right.text = innerCardData.topSubtitle
                                        tv_arrow_right.setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.icon)
                                    }
                                   
                                }
                            } else {
                                Timber.d("HomePageWidget fix Card bottom")
                                layoutFixVeryShortBottom.apply {
                                    imgTypeShortBottom.makeGone()
                                    makeVisible()
                                    val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                                    params.apply {
                                        width = innerCardData.innerCardWidth!!
                                        height = innerCardData.innerCardHeight!!
                                    }
                                    layoutParams = params
                                    if (innerCardData.position.equals("left")) {
                                        this.imgLeftImageOnly.makeGone()
                                        val bg = this.containerLeftBg.background
                                        val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(bg)
                                        try {
                                            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                                                drawable,
                                                Color.parseColor(innerCardData.cardTopBgColor)
                                            )
                                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                                            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                                                drawable,
                                                Color.parseColor("#699FFD")
                                            )
                                            Timber.e("Home page error wrong color")
                                        }
                                        this.containerLeftBg.background = drawable

                                        tv_item_title_left.text = innerCardData.title
                                        tv_price_left.text = innerCardData.topTitle
                                        tv_location_left.text = innerCardData.subtitle
                                        tv_price_change_left.text = innerCardData.topSubtitle
                                        tv_arrow_left.setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.icon)
                                    } else {
                                        this.imgRightImageOnly.makeGone()
                                        val bg = this.containerRightBg.background
                                        val drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(bg)
                                        try {
                                            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                                                drawable,
                                                Color.parseColor(innerCardData.cardTopBgColor)
                                            )
                                            this.containerRightBg.background = drawable
                                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                                            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                                                drawable,
                                                Color.parseColor("#699FFD")
                                            )
                                            Timber.e("Home page error wrong color")
                                        }


                                        tv_item_title_right.text = innerCardData.title
                                        tv_price_right.text = innerCardData.topTitle
                                        tv_location_right.text = innerCardData.subtitle
                                        tv_price_change_right.text = innerCardData.topSubtitle
                                        tv_arrow_right.setImageFromUrl(innerCardData.icon)
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }

                      
    }
}
```

setDimensionsMethod()

```
 private fun setCardsDimensions(binding: Any) {
    when (binding) {
        is RvItemHomePageTrendingNowBinding -> {
            binding.apply {
                container.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    homePageResponseItem?.cardHeight!!
                )
                homePageResponseItem?.cardSpaceMargin?.let {
                    container.margin(left = it / 2, right = it / 2)
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Trending Now/ Mix type card xml layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_type_long"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_height="208dp"
        tools:layout_width="150dp" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/img_type_short_top"
        tools:layout_width="158dp"
        tools:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@color/colorTextBlack" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView

        android:id="@+id/img_type_short_bottom"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:background="@color/colorTextBlack"
        tools:layout_height="95dp"
        tools:layout_width="158dp" />

    <include
        tools:visibility="visible"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/layout_fix_very_short_bottom"
        layout="@layout/rv_item_home_page_fix_veryshort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <include
        tools:visibility="gone"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/layout_fix_very_short_top"
        layout="@layout/rv_item_home_page_fix_veryshort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: please share code as to what you are doing. We cant do much with just images.

Comment: I've added the code it's huge, I can help you understand the code at any point. Thanks